# Как в PHP из строк выбрать только идущие в определенном порядке?

Tags: php

Как выбрать только строки (читаем из файла) в которых идет сначала:

1. Сначала '<Upload' или '<SUpload'
2. потом 'name'
3. потом 'ftpServer'

Т.е строки в которых нет такого порядка следования не нужны.

```
string(10) "<Upload"
string(19) "name = events"
string(36) "ftpServer = s1.ru"
string(10) "<SUpload"
string(16) "name = s33"
string(36) "ftpServer = 192.168.0.68"
string(16) "name = name1"
string(25) "name = name22_test"
string(10) "<Upload"
string(19) "name = name44"
string(36) "ftpServer = 192.168.0.69"
```

Должно получиться:

```
string(10) "<Upload"
string(19) "name = events"
string(36) "ftpServer = s1.ru"
string(10) "<SUpload"
string(16) "name = s33"
string(36) "ftpServer = 192.168.0.68"
string(10) "<Upload"
string(19) "name = name44"
string(36) "ftpServer = 192.168.0.69"
```

Comment: это массив?????

Comment: Нет строки из файла. Можно загнать в массив.

Comment: $file = file("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\index\\text.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES ); print_r($file); получишь массив, по условию if при foreach пробегаешь и удаляешь в массиве. потом все опять  записываешь в файл file_put_contents("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\index\\text1.txt", implode(PHP_EOL, $file));

Comment: Условия if какое должно быть? Читать по 3 элемента массива если первый содержит Upload ?

Comment: Читать по 3 элемента, проверять каждый из них, если хотя бы один не совпадает, то перейти к элементу `$i + 1`. Если всё совпало, то следующий элемент `$i + 3`

Comment: Вы уже описали нужные вам условия. Проходитесь по массиву и проверяйте каждую строку на соответствие вашим правилам.

Comment: Если файл не слишком большой - считайте его в массив. Объедините все элементы массива в одну строку. Дальше регулярным выражением выберите только, что Вам нужны и заново сохраните результаты по-строчно в нужном формате

Answer (score 0):

Загнать в массив, пробежаться по массиву и отобрать нужное. Как-то так:

```
for( $i=0; $i<count($lines)-2; $i++){
    if( preg_match('/<S?Upload/', $lines[$i] && preg_match('/name/', $lines[$i+1] && preg_match('/ftpServer/', $lines[$i+2] ){
        $result[]=$lines[$i];
        $result[]=$lines[$i+1];
        $result[]=$lines[$i+2];
    }
}
```